# Monorepo Yarn workspaces with Typescript in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, yarnpkg, monorepo

I create several repositories using Yarn Workspaces. Web works fine just my VSCode and Typescript (maybe eslint - but I do not use it in this project) are not happy with my monorepo. When I make import it shows

> Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type
> declarations.ts(2307)

[image]

but when I try to find in available packages than all works fine again:

[image]

Can someone help me with this issue?